# Connect to fortivpn config using openvpn?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Hello guys I have idiot question about vpns.
Can i connect to fortivpn config using openvpn gui?
I have more connections in open and wonna to have all in one client?
This is possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can connect to fortivpn with openvpn gui. You have to install fortinet client (https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux).

I use it and it works fine. I can be even connected in two VPNs at the same time. One openvpn and other fortivpn.